# Prove off by one cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that $|A\setminus\{a\}|=|A|-1$, where $\{a\}\subseteq A$?

This is part of an assignment for a software verification class, where I'm trying to prove a few theorems in Event-B. None of the automated provers I've used can prove it automatically.

EDIT: $A$ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess $A$ is supposed to be of finite size. By definition, there is a bijection $f$ from $A$ to $\{1,...,n\}$ (where $n$ is the size of A). Then let $k = f(a)$. By composion with another bijection of $\{1,...,n\}$ to itself we can suppose that $k = n$. By restricting $f$ to $A - \{a\}$, we have a bijection from $A - \{a\}$ to $\{1,...,n-1\}$. This means exactly that $A - \{a\}$ has size $n-1 = |A| - 1$.

Edit : $n$ is the size of $A$

Comment: I understand your reasoning and I really think the problem itself seems quite simple, however I just can't get the provers to prove it. I got as far as creating the bijetion $f$ from $A$ to $\{1,...,n\}$, but for some reason the prover just won't accept that $|A|=n$, and thus is also doesn't accept that $|A| - \{a\}=n-1$. I'm looking for a different proof here. Also at this point it might help to say that in fact $A$ is a range restriction of $B$ and $B \in C \rightarrow D$, where $C$ and $D$ are finite sets.